# Div fills the remaining space

Tags: html, wrapper

I have a site with 4 **`div`** tags:

1. Header (for navigation etc)
2. Logoheader (for a Logo)
3. content (my site content)
4. footer (for additional information)

the header and logo **`div`** should have a fix height and both should be 100% in their widht.

the footer **`div`** has a fix height of 132px and should be at the very bottom of the page.

The content **`div`** should fill the rest of the space which is left between the logoheader and the footer.

Here my code:

html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

    <link href="_css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
       <div id="headerWrapper"></div>
       <div id="logoWrapper"></div>
       <div id="contentWrapper"></div>
       <div id="footerWrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
body, html {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#headerWrapper {
    background-color: #ff6b2b;
    height: 45px;
}

#logoWrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#contentWrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: red;
}

#footerWrapper {
    background-color: #ff6a2b;
    height: 132px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

The outcome isnt really what I was looking for, maybe someone can help me to fix this problem. Because the whole site should be visible without scrolling.

Greetings :)

Comment: 100% will be inherited from the parent element (body) meaning it has nothing to do with the positions of the surrounding elements (header, footer, etc)

Comment: Flexboxes are what you need. A (very) well-made guide : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/